# How to change Visible panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want create a Tab Panel with link buttons, my code is:

```
// create title panel 
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Ctrl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Concat("<li role=\"presentation\" class=\"rightcolomn\">")));
    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
    lb.ID = i.ToString();
    lb.Text =i.ToString();
    lb.Click += new EventHandler(this.lbnTitle_Click); 
    Ctrl.Controls.Add(lb);
    Ctrl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</li>"));
}

// this code we create panels
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Panel pn = new Panel();
    pn.ID = "p" + i.ToString();
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        //some code add to panel                    
    }
    pn.Visible = false;
    Ctrl.Controls.Add(pn);
}

// code for link button click is:
protected void lbnTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton ClickedLink = (LinkButton)sender;            
}
```

When I click the link button, I want the corresponding panel to be set to visible, something like this: `panel("p"+linkbutton.ID).Visible=true`

how can access to panel and do it?

`Ctrl` is an `asp:PlaceHolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use control-IDs with numbers only, it's unlikely that they will be unique and it's also not very meaningful. However, use `FindControl` on the `NamingContainer`.

```
protected void lbnTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton ClickedLink = (LinkButton) sender;
    Control container = ClickedLink.NamingContainer;
    Panel panel = (Panel) container.FindControl("p" + ClickedLink.ID);
    panel.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string placeHolderId = "...";
string panelId = "p" + linkbutton.ID; 

(this.Form.FindControl("placeHolderId").FindControl("panelId") as Panel).Visible=true;
```